# Shared library fetching fails if LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't exported

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, shared-library, ld, ld.so.conf

By looking at `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` there is a `libc.conf` file that point to `/usr/local/lib` that contains the `.so` file necessary to run my application correctly. Even running `ldconfig -v` it is showed that the above path is set yet when I launch my program it fails to run the library contained in there. I must `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"` in order to correctly execute it but I need it to be set every time a new shell is open, so I tried to add the environment variable either to `/etc/environment` or `/home/user/.profile` or even `/home/user/.bashrc` without any success.

What's the correct way to set that variable permanently and why it is failing to pick the library even though a `.conf` file is pointing to the correct path?

EDIT:

`ldd /usr/local/lib`

```
asant@ANTONIO-PC:~$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libsqlcipher.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff25d9e000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f133d2f2000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f133d2cf000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f133d0dd000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f133d6c5000)
asant@ANTONIO-PC:~$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libsqlcipher.so.0
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcaede4000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f02bb35d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f02bb33a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f02bb148000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f02bb730000)
asant@ANTONIO-PC:~$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libsqlcipher.so.0.8.6
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe7daa7000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff66585b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff665838000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff665646000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff665c2e000)
```

Comment: Could you show the output of `ldd /path/to/your/binary`?

Comment: @StephenKitt added

Comment: I was interested in the output for the binary you’re trying to run, not the library (although that’s useful too).

Comment: It's a python program and it raises a ModuleNotFound error